# Create "query methods" in Peewee Models Python

Tags: python, flask, peewee

i'm using Peewee for MySQL connection in a flask project. I would like to know if it's possible to make querys in Method of a model. That would make the route code cleaner, For Example:

Person.py:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # This model uses the "people.db" database.

    def getPersonByName(name):
        #logic to get persons by name
        #return result
```

Server.py:

```
 .
 .
 .
 @app.route('/<name>')
 def index(name):
     persons = Person.getPersonByName(name)
     return render_template('names.html', persons=persons)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom methods can be added to a model to make *queries* so that models are kept fat and views kept slim.

```
class Person(Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def get_person_by_name(cls, name):
        result = cls.select().where(cls.name == name)
        return result


 @app.route('/<name>')
 def index(name):
     persons = Person.get_person_by_name(name)
     return render_template('names.html', persons=persons)
```