# How to avoid circular imports in Peewee when using query class methods on models?

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys, peewee

When using Peewee I follow the advice from the [Create "query methods" in Peewee Models Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898990/create-query-methods-in-peewee-models-python) answer:

```py
class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def adults(cls):
        return cls.select().where(cls.age > 18)
```

I create class methods for all my queries to keep my model "fat" and everything else "thin". Now I introduced a foreign key and I'm struggling with this approach, because Peewee requires me to use model class directly in the query:

```py
class Metric(Model):
    person = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='metrics')
    name = CharField()
    value = IntegerField()
```

Other file:

```py
class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def popular(cls, min_likes):
        return cls.select(cls, Metric).join(Metric).where(Metric.name == 'likes', Metric.value > min_likes)
```

This won't work, as the `Metric` definition depends on `Person` and vice versa, **causing a circular import**. The documentation has a section [Circular foreign key dependencies](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#circular-foreign-key-dependencies), where the solution to similar situations is `DeferredForeignKey`, but I don't like it, as it adds overhead in code (foreign keys need to be created manually everywhere) and because my app is using SQLite - the docs explicitly state the following:

> Because SQLite has limited support for altering tables, foreign-key constraints cannot be added to a table after it has been created.

If I understand it correctly, that effectively means I'd actually lose the FK constraint completely. I want the constraint though, the app relies on the fact that records with missing counterparts throw exceptions.

Is there a different workaround I'm overlooking? Is having fat models like this a recommended practice with Peewee after all? I like it, but it got me into a dead end in my models design. The docs even say:

> My personal opinion is that circular foreign keys are a code smell and should be refactored (by adding an intermediary table, for instance).

---

**Update:** I updated the question as originally I unintentionally omitted the main detail: I'm coping with circular *imports*, not just *dependencies* between the classes. If I collocate the classes to one file, it's gonna work, because Python resolves the names in classmethods only when they're called, but that's not what I'm solving, I'd like to keep the classes in separate modules.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand Python scoping. There's nothing wrong with referencing a related model inside a method body, e.g.:

```
# Move metric below Person.
class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def popular(cls, min_likes):
        return cls.select(cls, Metric).join(Metric).where(Metric.name == 'likes', Metric.value > min_likes)


class Metric(Model):
    person = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='metrics')
    name = CharField()
    value = IntegerField()
```

Alternatively you can use `DeferredForeignKey` which is built *exactly* for this purpose.

Comment: Oh! I skipped one part in my question which, I realized only after your answer, is perhaps essential to my problem. The code I have suffers from circular _imports_, as I keep every model in a separate file. As you correctly note, in a single file Python doesn't have a problem referencing stuff which doesn't exist yet, that is in functions.

Comment: I'm unsure now if I should accept your answer as it's a correct answer to the question asked, or whether I should edit my question to address my actual problem :(

Comment: You omitted the main detail. The circular import problem is solved by putting both models in the same file or introducing a 3rd module that imports the other two.

Comment: I omitted it unintentionally - tired to simplify my example for StackOverflow and didn't realize that imports are the main problem, because in the same file Python resolves the names. 3rd module is a traditional way to avoid circ. imports, but the classmethods belong to the model classes, so it's impossible to achieve.

Comment: Would you please edit your answer or post a new one, which says something along the lines of "the only sensible solution to your problem is to put those two models into a single file"? I'd like to mark that as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an ugly workaround. For the sake of completeness I'm posting it as an answer to my own question, but I don't like the solution, so I won't accept it as the answer.

Given the package structure looks like this:

```
models/
    __init__.py
    person.py
    metric.py
```

And given the `__init__.py` looks something like this:

```py
from .person import Person
from .metric import Metric
```

*Allows for simplified importing: `from models import Person` instead of `from models.person import Person`*

Then the workaround could be an ugly third file with just the properties of one of the models. For example, `person_attrs.py`:

```
models/
    __init__.py
    person.py
    person_attrs.py
    metric.py
```

The files would have the following contents. Person:

```py
class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()
```

Metric:

```py
from .person import Person

class Metric(Model):
    person = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='metrics')
    name = CharField()
    value = IntegerField()
```

Person attributes:

```py
from .metric import Metric

__all__ = ['popular']

@classmethod
def popular(cls, min_likes):
    return cls.select(cls, Metric).join(Metric).where(Metric.name == 'likes', Metric.value > min_likes)
```

Then the `__init__.py` works as the glue:

```py
from .person import Person
from .metrics import Metric


from . import person_attrs  # isort:skip

for attr_name in person_attrs.__all__:
    setattr(Person, attr_name, getattr(person_attrs, attr_name))
```

The workaround abuses `__all__` (but I think it's still better to be explicit than to look up the attributes with an implicit algorithm), and the order of imports in `__init__.py` becomes significant. The `person_attrs.py` allows for defining both `@classmethod` and `@property` methods, which can now use the other model `Metric` freely as they wish, but for the price of being expelled into a separate file as top-level objects, only to be united with the `Person` model in the `models` package root.

Obviously not nice, not straightforward, kinda ugly, but I couldn't come up with anything else yet apart from putting the models together into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't already have an actual reference loop and your `__init__.py` file is just making imports easier, use absolute imports IN the modules themselves (avoids worrying about import order in `__init__.py`. Your shorthand imports will still be useful everywhere else in your codebase. Then, simply defer the import of Metric into the classmethod itself.

Given the layout you specified:

```
models/
__init__.py
person.py
metric.py
```

Your `__init__.py` should look like this:

```
from .person import Person
from .metric import Metric

__all__ = ("Person", "Metric", )
```

Then `person.py` should look like this:

```
from peewee import Model

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def popular(cls, min_likes):
        from models.metric import Metric  # Import deferred
        return cls.select(cls, Metric).join(Metric).where(Metric.name == 'likes', Metric.value > min_likes)
```

And `metric.py` simply like this:

```
from peewee import Model
from models.person import Person

class Metric(Model):
    person = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='metrics')
    name = CharField()
    value = IntegerField()
```

Now, if you want to get a bit more fancy and you're not wanting to have to constantly invoke the import framework you could do:

```
    from peewee import Model

    class Person(Model):
        name = CharField()
        age = IntegerField()

        @classmethod
        def popular(cls, min_likes):
            try:
                Metric = cls.MetricKlass
            except AttributeError:
                Metric = getattr(__import__("models.metric"), "Metric")
                cls.MetricKlass = Metric
            return cls.select(cls, Metric).join(Metric).where(Metric.name == 'likes', Metric.value > min_likes)
```

... which will stash the import on the class so you can just retrieve it there. I doubt that's really worth it though.